# How to design the classes in scala when you want to mock a heavy method in testing?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, traits

I have a class named `HtmlConverter` which can convert a html page into plain text files, and it can retrieve the html content from a url.

I want to unit-test it, so I want to mock the part of "retrieving html from url" part. Now I have two options:

#### 1. Define an object `HtmlRetriever` and use it in `HtmlConverter`

Code:

```
class HtmlRetriever {
    def getContentFromUrl(url:String) = { 
        // heavy work
    }
}

class HtmlConverter {
    val retriever = new HtmlRetriever
    def convertFromUrl(url:String) = {
         val content = retriever.getContentFromUrl(url)
         // convert
    }
}
```

When testing, use `mockito` and `spec2`:

```
object MyHtmlConverter extends HtmlConverter {
    override val retriever = mock[HtmlRetriever]
}

MyHtmlConverter.retriever.getContentFromUrl(...) returns "<html>...</html>"

val pdf = MyHtmlConterter.convertFromUrl(...)

// assert the invocation
there was one(MyHtmlConverter.retriever).getContentFromUrl(...)
```

This works, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution

#### 2. Use trait

Now I want to try a trait

```
trait HtmlRetriever {
    def getContentFromUrl(url:String) = { 
        // heavy work
    }
}

class HtmlConverter extends HtmlRetriever {
    def convertFromUrl(url:String) = {
         val content = getContentFromUrl(url)
         // convert
    }
}
```

When testing, I can't find a way to use `mockito`, I can just use my custom overriding method:

```
object MyHtmlConverter extends HtmlConverter {
    override def getContentFromUrl(url:String) = "<html>from test</html"
}
```

Then test the object `MyHtmlConverter` with the new `getContentFromUrl` method.

In this way, I can't use `mockito` so that I can't verify the invocations like:

```
there was one(htmlRetriever).getContentFromUrl(...)
```

Which I neither satisfied

Is there any best practice to do this kind of testing in scala, with `mockito` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a declaration of a class that extends the trait in your test and then mock that class:

```
class TestHtmlConverter extends HtmlConverter

/* other code elided */
val htmlConverter = mock[TestHtmlConverter]
htmlConverter.getContentFromUrl(/* ... */) returns "<html />"
```

Comment: But I still want to test the real logic of `HtmlConverter#convertFromUrl`, so you mean I need to use `spy`?

Comment: If you want to test the real logic of `#convertFromUrl` test it in its own unit test, and mock its behavior in other tests that depend upon its output.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your method differently to avoid needing the mock at all.

```
class HtmlConverter {
    val retriever = new HtmlRetriever
    def convertFromUrl(url:String) = {
         val content = retriever.getContentFromUrl(url)
         convert(content)
    }
    def convert(content: ContentFromUrl) = {
        // convert
    }
}
```

Then you can simply test `convert` directly. A different suite of tests can cover `retriever`, and your `convertFromUrl` method is now simple enough to not need a direct unit test.